# The domain onto or into or neither?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is actually related to the semantics of *onto*

If  $f(x)=\sin(x)$
is $f(x)$ *onto*  the set $[0,1]$?
This a question from *Real Analysis and Probability* by Dudley (page 9).

I am confused because if a set $B\subset{}range(f)$ (here the $range(f)=[-1,1]$) then can you say that $f$ is onto $B$?

Comment: Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a function. Then $f$ being onto some $B'\subseteq B$ means that for any $b\in B'$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Or equivalently $B'\subseteq\text{im}(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is onto the set $[0, 1].\,$ For every $y \in [0, 1]$, there exists an $x$ such that $\sin x = y$.

Indeed, for every $y_i\in [0, 1]$, there exists an $x_i=\arcsin y_i$, where $x_i$ is in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that our environment of discourse is ${\mathbb R}$. Given an expression $\Phi(x)$ in terms of a variable $x$, like $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, the domain of the function $f(x):=\Phi(x)$, like $f(x):=\sqrt{4-x^2}$, *if not otherwise specified*, is the largest subset of ${\mathbb R}$ for which $\Phi(x)$ can be evaluated without asking questions. Therefore the domain of $f(x):=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is  the interval $[-2,2]$, and the domain of $f(x):=\sin x$ is ${\mathbb R}$.

Given this, the function $f(x):=\sin x$, without additional utterings, maps ${\mathbb R}$ onto $[-1,1]\,$, and nothing else. But we are always allowed to say that the *restriction* of $f$ to the interval $I:=\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ maps $I$ onto $[0,1]$.